# Sign a message with Ethereum private key on Java

Tags: java, ethereum, digital-signature, private-key

I need to sign a message with a blockchain private key using Java.

Something like
const signature = await ethersSigner.signMessage(message);
on JavaScript.

Thanks a lot

Don't find this method in web3j

Answer (score 1):

you can find more here https://blog.web3labs.com/web3development/how-to-sign-messages-with-web3j

but here is a simple example of signing a message in java

```
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.crypto.Sign;
import org.web3j.utils.Numeric;

public class SignMessageExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String privateKey = "0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef";
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privateKey);

        String message = "Hello, world!";
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes();
        Sign.SignatureData signature = Sign.signMessage(messageBytes, credentials.getEcKeyPair());

        String r = Numeric.toHexString(signature.getR());
        String s = Numeric.toHexString(signature.getS());
        String v = Numeric.toHexString(signature.getV());

        System.out.println("Signature: r=" + r + " s=" + s + " v=" + v);
    }
}
```